# Getting the sum of an array with time PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can i get the sum of this array, i have tried to search for this without any luck.

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "7.14" } 0<br>
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "5.0" } 0<br>
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "15.26" } 0<br>
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "15.32" } 0<br>
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "15.33" } 0<br>
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "15.34" } 0<br>
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "1.0" } 0<br>
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "0.0" } 0<br>
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "0.2" } 0<br>
```

It is important to know that the values of the array is in `time` format. so when 2 values is like `15.34 + 15.33 = 30.67 = 30.60 + 0.07` the sum will be `31.07`.
**Code behind:**

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM timer WHERE id = '10'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $inn = date("H:i", strtotime($row['inn']));
       $ut = date("H:i", strtotime($row['ut']));

    $from = new DateTime($inn);
    $to = new DateTime($ut);
    $timer = $from->diff($to)->format('%h.%i');

    $a = var_dump(explode(" ", $timer));
    $test = array($a);
    echo array_sum($test) . "<br>";
    };
```

Im a real noob to this so please help :)

Comment: you want to convert to seconds then do the math and convert to display format.

Comment: What datatype are inn and ut on your database?

Comment: Inn and ut is time type in mysql db. This is a db for registering working houres, and i want to sum all the hours the employer has worked based on inn and ut(out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total interval, you can either convert each interval to seconds and add them up like Dagon suggested, or use to variables to track start time and end time, then find the difference:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM timer WHERE id = '10'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$start = new Datetime();
$end = clone $start;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $inn = date("H:i", strtotime($row['inn']));
    $ut = date("H:i", strtotime($row['ut']));

    $from = new DateTime($inn);
    $to = new DateTime($ut);
    $interval = $from->diff($to);
    $end->add($interval);
    $timer = $interval->format('%h.%i');

    $a = var_dump(explode(" ", $timer));
    $test = array($a);
    echo array_sum($test) . "<br>";
};

$sum_interval = $start->diff($end);
```

Comment: When i try to echo $sum_interval i get nothing

Comment: Ok i did this and now i get a number but it is not right i should get 53 and something but i get 9 and something so there is something wrong?

Comment: I got it to work, there was some data sett to 0 in db.

Comment: @user3168230, glad you figured it out.